# PC don't start the and no beeps from BIOS on power on

Tags: black-screen-of-death

A friend just brought me hi's PC because it doesn't start. 
I have no bios beeps, no screen activation. The monitor stays blank and nothing is on the display.

Does anyone knows how can we fix this? Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://superuser.com/questions/118931/black-screen-when-computer-boots

Comment: Having had this happen to me recently - if the fans turn but there's no beeps even when you remove all the memory modules then it's the motherboard that dead.

Comment: No beebs huh? Is your friend a tween girl? If not, then they’re probably not a fan of Justin Bieber anyway. ;)

Comment: @ChrisF: ty. it were the memory module.

Answer (score 3):

Open the PC, do the fans work? If yes, the motherboard or CPU might be broken, if even the fans do not turn, it's most likely the PSU.

Answer (score 1):

First, remove the power plug for few seconds. Then replug it and check. Maybe the power supply is in security mode. If it doesn't change anything, the power supply is dead or there is a shortcut or an over limit current. Try to unplug internal power cables on hard drive, etc and test again.